# Xcode 8 Generate .strings File

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to work on setting up my Xcode project to generate I believe a XLIFF for each language I want to translate into to send to a [translating service](http://www.ibabbleon.com) to have my app translated. I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html) but I'm still struggling with it.

When adding a language to translate into my storyboard's created a .strings file and took all of my text from my storyboard's and put it into the .strings file and did it all automatically.

Now I'm trying to get it to work for strings in my Swift files. For example I changed `"Error"` to be `NSLocalizedString("error", tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "Error", comment: "Error Alert Controller Title")` in my code.

Problem is it doesn't create any `.strings` file like it did for the storyboard. So when it try to go to `Editor > Export For Localization` it gives me an error saying `Localization failed to read a strings file`.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm assuming I can manually create `.strings` files but this seems like a huge pain and seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: You create the localization file manually once.  If you find something painful, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @ElTomato So I have a ton of strings. For Storyboards it creates the .strings file automatically. It can't do that for Swift NSLocalizedString's?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a way to generate strings file.

Open your Mac’s Terminal app, then change into the directory where your project’s `ViewController.swift` file is.

Now run this command:

```
genstrings -o en.lproj *.swift
```

**This means:** read all Swift files for localized strings, then write them out to the localized strings file for the English project.

It will list out all the strings that you wrote in your code using `NSLocalizedString`.